# Difficulties in understanding keras source code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am reading a code in keras and I don't understand a line. The code is the following:

```
from keras import initializers
from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate
from keras.layers import Input

m = 1
n = 1
N = 20

a = Input(shape=(m,))
b = Input(shape=(m,))
c = Input(shape=(1,))
d = Input(shape=(1,))
inputs = [a, b, d, c]
output_state = []
layers = []

for j in range(N):
    for i in range(n):
        layer = Dense(m, activation='tanh', trainable=True, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(0, 1),
                      bias_initializer='random_normal', name=str(i) + str(j))
        layers = layers + [layer]

for j in range(N):
    helper1 = Concatenate()([a, b])
    for i in range(n):
        temp = layers[i + j * n](helper1)
```

The line that I don't understand is the last one. They are defining a neural network such that each layer has an input of dimension 2*(m+1). the part

```
(helper1)
```

seems to me as an input of one of the layer, which doesn't make sense since helper doesn't have dimension 2*(m+1). For that reason I wanted to ask what's happening in the last line of the code.

Comment: Where do you get from that the layers have input dimension 2(m+1)?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm not sure, but I think that the dimension of the input vector is given by inputs=[a,b,c,d], which has shape (2(m+1), ).

Comment: You need to be sure, its basically your question. The layers have input which is a concatenation of a and b (2m dimensions), so I am not sure what exactly you are asking, as 2(m+1) makes no sense.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I thought that the vector 'inputs' was the actual input of the layer and it is of dimension 2*(m+1). But that's not the case. Is 'temp' the output?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Is 'temp' the output?